# Hi, Looking for a JES alternative

Tags: eclipse, pydev, jython, jes

I asked a variant of this question before and it got closed as "off topic", no idea why.

I'm studying Jython for uni and Hate using jython.  I have tried using pydev but things like "pickAFile()" aren't recognised.

`NameError: global name 'pickAFile' is not defined`

Is there another plugin, or file I can add, so I can run code that runs in JES to run on something like PyDev?

Edit:  I'm not sure of the terminology but I guess I'm looking for something like a Jython script that I can addon to accept JES statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sought an alternative too, I find JES overly limited and buggy - it's part of an archaic teaching methodology.

JES itself uses a cut-down version of Jython, so it's not compatible with either Python, Java or Jython in general and there's precious little documentation of any kind.

The reason PyDev and Eclipse (with the Jython plugin) won't work for you is that they don't have the included classes - some of which are written in Java, some in Python.

If you know your way around (which new students almost certainly won't) you can copy out relevant classes to your preferred IDE and maybe make a small library to #import but at the end of the day you'll still need to do the majority of your work in JES because it needs to work in JES when it's submitted.